# Format numbers right-justification in php with sprintf

Tags: php, mysql

I get numbers from a MySQL DB and put them in a dynamic table, every number in  a different line. The problem is that the numbers are left-aligned, and that looks dirty, like

```
125
2
78
```

I want a output like:

```
125
  2
 78
```

I use the following output from the database:

```
echo "<td>".$dataset['minutenstaffel']."</td>";
```

**Format the `<td>` is no option.**

I tried with sprintf but this doesnt work:

```
echo "<td>".printf("%s",$dataset['trikotnr'])."</td>";
```

Thank you!!

Comment: `"Format the <td> is no option."` Huh? Please explain - the answer should be some simple css

Comment: Yes, but with align right  the whole table looks dirty, there must be another solution like sprintf or something

Comment: like  , how does it look dirty , you can use margin-right:10px; along with text-align:right; after placing the numbers in a span

Comment: do you know how to use the sprintf function to make that working?

Comment: Please update your question to state that this needs to work with the [table reflow feature](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.3.0-beta.1/docs/tables/table-reflow.html) in jQuery mobile.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spaces in HTML are reduced to a single space upon rendering, so the added spaces won't do anything. The exception is when using `<pre>`. This is really a styling issue though.

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr><td>
    <span class="align-numbers">123</span>
  </td></tr>
  <tr><td>
    <span class="align-numbers">1234567</span>
  </td></tr>
  <tr><td>
    <span class="align-numbers">1</span>
  </td></tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
td .align-numbers {
    float: right;
    font-family: monospace;
}
```

Codepen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LGPjNa

This code should work with jQuery mobile's table reflow feature. Make sure your PHP wraps the values in a `<span class="align-numbers">` so the CSS applies correctly.

Comment: Thanks aross. I used the css, but the text align has no effect.Maybe thats why I use jquery mobile for the css

Comment: Then there must be some other CSS that overwrites this rule. Check your browser's developer tools.

Comment: Yes, the rule came from jquery, thats why I want to use php instead of css

Comment: Do you have control over the jQuery code that applies the styling? You're trying to work around the actual problem, but it may be better to solve the actual problem itself.

Comment: OK, so the problem is that jQuery mobile adds markup in the `td` so it can reflow the table when needed. I'll adjust my answer with code that ought to work in that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

use style `text-align:right`

```
echo "<td style="text-align:right">".$dataset['minutenstaffel']."</td>";
```

Comment: As i wrote, text align is no option, i dont want to have the numbers at the right margin.

Comment: but why ?? i think there is no more options are available @Ronny

Comment: cause the table should be responsive, and if you have all on the right it just looks dirty. Span would be a option, but then the table isnt responsive anymore.

Answer (score 0):

text-align:right

```
echo '<td style="text-align:righ">'.$dataset['minutenstaffel'].'</td>
```

Comment: <code>echo "<td style=\"text-align:right\">".$dataset['trikotnr']."</td>";
</code> would be correct, but its no option

Answer (score 0):

**It's working for me like this **
just add span and  'style="float: right !important';

```
 $nestedData[] = '<span style="float: right !important;">'.number_format($DR['montant'], 2, ',', ' ').'</span>';
```